# PHP - Preg match URL

Tags: php, preg-match

I wish to know how I can do something, if the pattern/first string of a URL is something specific.

Currently, I get the **current** url like this:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/profile"){echo "class='selected'";} ?>
```

Although, I want to know how I can apply the above code to /profile **and** to URLs that contains "/profile" - for example:

```
/profile/???
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `'/^(\/profile)(\/|$)/'` as your preg_match pattern.

Source code:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\/profile)(\/|$)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That is Much better and answers the question ( if I had only read it correctly in the first place ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

if(preg_match("@/profile@",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) > 0){echo "class='selected'";}

I have used the '@' character as the delimiters for the regex to be different.

Comment: It will return true for "/profiler" and "/user/profile" as well.

Comment: Yes it will return TRUE if /profile is anywhere in the URI.